# How to make redirect in nested routes with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After signin process my app redirects to /admin/dashboard , and when entering dashboard path i want my app to load first component  and redirect to /admin/dashboard/profiles. In App.js component i have code

```
<Router>
    <Layout>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        ...
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
        ...
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  </Router>
```

In  component i have code

```
    <Layout>
      <Sidebar />
      <Switch>
        <PrivateRoute path={`${match.url}/profiles`} component={Profiles} />
        <PrivateRoute path={`${match.url}/tests`} component={Tests} />
        <PrivateRoute path={`${match.url}/settings`} component={Settings} />
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
```

It only loads  component when the path of first component is path={`${match.url}/`} , but when path is /admin/dashboard/profiles it does not render Profiles component. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an exact attribute on the top level route

```
<Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```

Which is why any nested route won't match. Remvove the exact attribute from the parent route and it would work for you

```
<Route path="/admin/dashboard" component={Dashboard}/>
```

Also for paths, you must use `match.path` instead of `match.url`. `match.url` should be used for `Link` and `Redirect` component